# Is it possible to use both routeContextRef and dataFormats elements in a camelContext?

Tags: apache-camel

When I attempt to do so, I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 35 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 35; columnNumber: 55; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'routeContextRef'. One of '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":redeliveryPolicyProfile, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":onException, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":onCompletion, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":intercept, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":interceptFrom, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":interceptSendToEndpoint, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":route}' is expected.
```

Checking the schema, it is apparently true that it's not possible to define routes within a routeContext that can use dataFormat since dataFormats elements must follow routeContextRef elements.

Do I need to abandon the routeContext organizational approach and put all my routes in a single file?

Here is a slightly bowdlerized version of the camel context. I need to be able to use json in cContext.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<beans
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<import resource="classBeanDefs.xml"/>
<import resource="a.xml"/>
<import resource="b.xml"/>
<import resource="c.xml"/>

<camelContext id="camel" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <propertyPlaceholder id="properties"
                         location="classpath:route.properties"
                         xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"/>

    <dataFormats>
        <json id="json" library="Jackson"/>
    </dataFormats>

    <routeContextRef ref="aContext"/>
    <routeContextRef ref="bContext"/>
    <routeContextRef ref="cContext"/>
</camelContext>

</beans>
```

I get a similar error when I try to add the dataFormats element to the routeContext, which the schema clearly doesn't approve of.

Comment: Show us your `context.xml`.

Comment: Steve any luck finding the solution?

Answer (score 4):

You should have your routeContextRef *before* the dataFormats.

Comment: Right, that's what the schema mandates. But in that case, it isn't applied to the routes defined in the routeContexts.

Comment: Yeah its most likely not possible. We have a ticket to improve on that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3870

Comment: Seems like I cannot even have <routeContextRef/> before <threadPoolProfile/> tag. I do not have any dataFormats in my context.xml